# Oracle Loader for .xlsx file

Tags: excel, oracle

I am tring to load a .xlsx file into an Oracle database table. I am getting an error for my code. I normally use this code for .csv files but need to use it for .xlsx I have edited my field names, table names etc
Is this possible?

```
Drop TABLE Temp_Info;
      CREATE TABLE Temp_Info
                           (
                             Unique_Id varchar2(255)  ,  
                             Name varchar2(255),  
                             Alt_Name varchar2(255)
                           )
             ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
             ( 
               TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
               DEFAULT DIRECTORY SEPA_FILES 
               ACCESS PARAMETERS 
               ( 
                 records delimited by newline  
                 skip 1 
                 fields terminated by ',' 
                 missing field values are null
                 ( 
                  Unique ID -(filled automatically),Name,Alt Name
                 )
               ) 
               LOCATION ('Data_File.xlsx') 
             ) 
             REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

`Select * From Temp_Info a;`

```
Error Message: 9:16:55  ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
9:16:55  ORA-29400: data cartridge error
9:16:55  KUP-00554: error encountered while parsing access parameters
9:16:55  KUP-01005: syntax error: found "identifier": expecting one of: "comma, char, date, defaultif, decimal, double, float, integer, (, nullif, oracle_date, oracle_number, position, raw, recnum, ), unsigned, varrawc, varchar, varraw, varcharc, zoned"
9:16:55  KUP-01008: the bad identifier was: ID
9:16:55  KUP-01007: at line 6 column 30
9:16:55  ORA-06512: at "SYS.ORACLE_LOADER", line 14
9:16:55  ORA-06
```

Comment: It's a .xlsx file? I can't actually post the data unfortunately (data privacy)

Comment: Oh, its `.xlsx` file. I think this file format is not supported by Oracle. You need to have `.csv` file.

Comment: Is there any alternative solution for .xlsx?

Answer (score 1):

1) Option [ Pure PL/SQL]

Xlsx document is zipped set of xml documents. You can change extension xlsx to zip, unzip and find out what is inside.
[Here](https://odieweblog.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/xml-db-events-reading-an-open-office-xml-document-xlsx/) is description how to deal with xlsx document in oracle environment. 
This solution works but implementation is very painful.

2) Option (PL/SQL + apache POI) 
Create implementation in java. And use it in db.

3) Convert xlxs to csv.

Comment: Thanks, Looking at option 2. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/saternos-tables-090560.html I know to change the file name in the bat file. Would you know where else needs to be modified for the attached folder?

Comment: Are you asking about  `load_dir AS 'C:\workspaces\test\XL2ExternalTables'` ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [ExcelTable](https://odieweblog.wordpress.com/2016/11/15/exceltable12/) SQL interface (Disclaimer : I'm the author).
It provides access to .xlsx (or .xlsm) files as an external table.

Here's an example based on your ext table definition :

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM TABLE(
       ExcelTable.getRows(
         ExcelTable.getFile('SEPA_FILES','Data_File.xlsx')
       , 'Sheet_name_goes_here'      
       , ' "UNIQUE_ID" for ordinality
         , "NAME"      varchar2(255)
         , "ALT_NAME"  varchar2(255) '
       , 'A2'
       )
     ) t ;
```

*(I assumed UNIQUE_ID is some kind of autogenerated sequence)*